# How to determine present database server name - sybase ase

Tags: sap-ase

I need to determine present databse server name where i am running my sql so that i can perform some certain steps depending upon the environment.

Anybody know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ASE database server name can be found in:

```
1) in interfaces file (UNIX) or using DSEDIT in Windows
2) running select * from master..sysservers
```

Comment: for me that returns more than one row

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT @@servername
```

Why? Because @@servername is a global variable and returns the name of the SAP ASE server.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ASEHostName()
```

on the ASE Instance will give you the Physical Machine Name , while

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

will give you the Database Server name that you would give when you setup ASE instance during installation.

-- In 'thoughts'...